# Круг из точек разного цвета

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал следующий код. Строится круг из точек. Может кто-то подскажет как раскрасить каждую точку в градиенте от белого к черному? Хотя бы рандомно

```
T = np.arange(1, 20, 1)
R = np.arange(1, 360, 2)

 for i in R:
   i = i * np.pi/180

   for z in T:
     x = z*0.5*np.cos(i)
     y = z*0.5*np.sin(i)

    plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Градиент по окружности распространяется или по плоскости?

Comment: Точки на плоскости, предполагается, что цвет каждой точки будет зависеть от значения в ней, вычисленного по некой формуле.

Comment: Ну снизу вот хороший ответ. Но опять же, градиент бывает линейный, а бывает радиальный. Если про линейный, то просто можете каждой координате Х проставить цвет, где 0 - белый, а крайнее значение Х - черный. Дальше просто распределите на каждый шаг  изменение цвета

Answer (score 1):

Я не совсем понял, как вы хотите распределять градиент, но в принципе, можете использовать colomaps:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

T = np.arange(1, 20, 1)
R = np.arange(1, 360, 2)
X = []
Y = []
Z = []
for i in R:
    i = i * np.pi/180
    for z in T:
        X.append(z*0.5*np.cos(i))
        Y.append(z*0.5*np.sin(i))
        Z.append(z)


plt.scatter(X, Y, c=Z, cmap=cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

Результат будет таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**

Я правда не совсем понимаю задачу, поставленную автором вопроса, но в ответ на комментарии могу добавить это (при условии, что все исходные данные те же:

```
X = sorted(X[::50]) #уменьшил размерность, поскольку иначе
Y = sorted(Y[::50]) #будет долго считаться mesh

X,Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y, indexing='ij')
Z = np.sqrt(X*X + Y*Y)
plt.imshow(Z, cmap='Greys', interpolation = 'bicubic')
plt.show()
```

В этом случае получим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо, можно воспользоваться `plt.pcolormesh`:

```
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y, indexing='ij')
Z = np.sqrt(X*X + Y*Y)
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap='Greys', shading='gouraud')
plt.show()
```

Тогда результат будет таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. А не подскажите ещё, как для такого рисунка сделать интерполяцию?

Comment: Вы не могли бы конкретизировать свой вопрос?

Comment: Для изображения использую imshow(data, interpolation='bicubic') , а как в scatter получить такой же эффект?

Comment: @strawdog не забудьте отметить данный вопрос как правильный, если ответ решил вашу проблему.